# Filtering Observable with Rxjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to get a list of active jobs for the current user:

```
jobListRef$: Observable<Job[]>;
...
this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data.uid) {
    this.jobListRef$ = this.database.list<Job>('job-list', query => {
         return query.orderByChild("state").equalTo("active");
    })
    .snapshotChanges().map(jobs => {
         return jobs.map(job => {
              const $key = job.payload.key;
              const data = { $key, ...job.payload.val() };
              return data as Job;
         });
    })
    .filter(val =>
         val.map(job => {
              return (job.employer == data.uid || job.employee == data.uid);
         })
    );
  }
});
```

The problem begins only at the filtering. According to the official documentation the right part of its argument should return boolean, so like in my case. But still it returns me whole entries without filtering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to reverse the map and filter operators.

```js
.map((jobs: Job[]) =>
  jobs.filter((job: Job) => job.employer === data.uid || job.employee === data.uid )
);
```

(`map` to transform one array into another, `filter` to reduce the array).

Or you can chain filter on to the map that performs the type-conversion,

```js
.map(jobs => {
  return jobs.map(job => {
    const $key = job.payload.key;
    const data = { $key, ...job.payload.val() };
    return data as Job;
  })
  .filter(job => job.employer === data.uid || job.employee === data.uid )
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I couldn't come to this on my own. :D

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the result of the `Array.map` call, see its return value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

It looks like you maybe want to use `map` instead of `filter`:

```
.snapshotChanges().map(...)
.map(val => val.map(job => {
   return (job.employer == data.uid || job.employee == data.uid);
}));
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work for me: I still get the same amount of elements, some of them are just completely empty. Since I'm trying to filter a List Observable, I need to check not **val** directly, but it's children.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the whole problem, but it might be something like:

```
this.jobListRef$ = this.afAuth.authState
    .filter(data => !!data && !!data.uid)
    .take(1)
    .switchMap(data =>
        this.database.list<Job>('job-list', query => query.orderByChild("state").equalTo("active"))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map(jobs =>
                jobs.map(job => {
                    const $key = job.payload.key;
                    const data = { $key, ...job.payload.val() };
                    return data as Job;
                })
            )
            .map((jobs: Job[]) =>
                jobs.filter(job => (job.employer == data.uid || job.employee == data.uid))
            )
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, you got me right. This one is similar to the answer of Richard Matsen

Comment: yeah. we were writing at the same time. glad you find the answer.