# UNABLE TO FILTER FIREBASE LIST USING SEARCH BAR

Tags: angular8

I am able to retrieve a list of users from firebase realtime database. However, I am stuck on how to apply a filter to my retrieved list, such that I can only see users who match what I’ve typed on the search bar.

I have followed the example on this site [Filtering Observable with Rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122974/filtering-observable-with-rxjs), which is similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

model.ts

```
export interface AppUser {
    userId: string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
    photoURL: string;
}
```

User.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminUserService {
  userRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/users').snapshotChanges();
  }

  get(id: string) {
    this.userRef = this.db.object('users/' + id);
    return this.userRef;
  }
```

User.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminUserService } from 'src/app/services/admin-user.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppUser } from 'src/app/models/app-user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  appUser: AppUser[];
  filteredUser: any[];

  constructor(private adminUserService: AdminUserService) {
    this.adminUserService.getAll()
    .pipe(map((users: any[]) => users.map(user => 
     ({ id:user.key,...user.payload.val() })
     ).filter(curUser => curUser.firstname === this.filteredUser)
    )
    );
   }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredUser = (query) ? this.appUser.filter(u => 
    u.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : 
    this.appUser;
  }
```

user.component.html

```
    <p>
        <a routerLink="/admin/users/new" class="btn btn-primary">New User</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="fom-
         control" placeholder="Search...">
    </p>

<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let u of filteredUser">
         <td>{{ u.firstname }} {{ u.lastname }}</td>
         <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
         <td>{{ u.phone }}</td>
         <td>{{ u.isAdmin }}</td>
         <td>
             <a [routerLink]="['/admin/users/', u.id]">Edit</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Up to this point I am not getting errors, but when i add filter method in component.ts file I get no list from firebase.

Comment: anyone with an answer to this question, or who can guide me to a post that will assist me to  figure it out?. I have been following oshop tutorial to do my first angular 8 project but all my efforts of trying to get data filtering to work has not bore fruits.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  appUser: AppUser[];
  filteredUser: AppUser[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private adminUserService: AdminUserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.adminUserService.getAll()
      .subscribe(a => this.filteredUser = this.appUser = a);
  }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredUser = (query) ?
      this.appUser.filter(u => u.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : 
     this.appUser;
    }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list('/users').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
          )
      );
  }

<tr *ngFor="let u of filteredUser">
  <td>{{ u.firstname }} {{ u.lastname }}</td>
  <td>
    <a [routerLink]="['/admin/users/', u.id]">Edit</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```